# SwiftUI Stepper - Not committing changes to view or environment objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

So, I have a settings page sheet in swiftui that (in theory) should allow the user to add and remove rows using a stepper, with each row signifying a number...the stepper lives at the bottom, and the whole thing is a scroll view...for whatever reason, when the view appears, I cannot get it to load the values from the environment and, when a value is changed, the environment doesn't update...I tried to set this up with copying environment properties to local @State properties on appear, then copying them back on disappear, but it didn't make a difference...

```
struct Settings_SetupNumbersView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnvironment_Main
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var tempText = ""
    
   
    
    var body: some View {
                
        return ZStack {
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button("DONE") {
                        self.isPresented.toggle()
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    
                    
                }
                
                Divider()
                
                if env.numbers.count == 0 {
                    //
                } else {
                    ScrollView {
                        ForEach(self.env.numbers.indices, id: \.self) { number in
                            ZStack {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(height: K.screenHeight / 15)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                        .frame(width: K.screenWidth / 20)
                                    
                                    Text("#\(self.env.numbers.count +  1)")
                                        .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 17.0))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(K.SettingsTextColor))
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    TextField("", text: $tempText, onCommit: {
                                        self.tempText = self.env.numbers[self.env.numbersIndex]
                                        print("number committed \(self.env.numbers[self.env.numbersIndex])")
                                        
                                    })
                                    .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 17.0))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(K.SettingsTextColor))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, K.screenWidth / 20)
                                    
                                    //                Spacer()
                                    //                    .frame(width: K.screenWidth / 20)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 20)
                    
                }
                if env.numbers.count == 0 {
                    Text("Tap Plus Button to Add a Number")
                        .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 17.0))
                        .foregroundColor(Color(K.SettingsTextColor))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.25)
                }
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: K.screenWidth / 20)
                    
                    Text("Add/Remove Numbers")
                        .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 17.0))
                        .foregroundColor(Color(K.SettingsTextColor))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.25)
                    
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Stepper(onIncrement: {
                        
                        self.env.numbers.append("12345")
                        print("Number should be added")
                        print(env.numbers.indices)
                        print(self.env.numbers)
                        print("count = \(self.env.numbers.count)")
                        
                    },
                    
                    onDecrement: {
                        
                        if self.env.numbers.count != 0 {
                            print("number should be removed")
                            
                            self.env.numbers = self.env.numbers.dropLast()
                            print(env.numbers.indices)
                            print(self.env.numbers)
                            print("count = \(self.env.numbers.count)")
                            
                        }
                        
                    }) {
                        
                        Text("")
                    }
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .padding(.vertical, K.screenHeight / 70)
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: K.screenWidth / 20)
                }
                
            }.onAppear(perform: {
                print(env.numbers.indices)
            })
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Is there a trick to SwiftUI where the sheet presentation can't update variables or something weird like that?  I'm at a loss, the layout of the sheet works and the values are going into the env according to the print statements, but when i dismiss the sheet and come back the values reset (and when I hit plus it removes the array it had been writing to and writes a new value)...if everything goes perfect, when I hit + a new row is added, - removes the last one, and if i dismiss the sheet and come back the same rows created are still there (based on values of the env.numbers array)

Comment: It looks like not here show how/where you create Settings_SetupNumbersView and GlobalEnvironment_Main

Comment: the global environment is created in the scene delegate, this settings_SetupNumbersView is created in a settings view (settings_SetupNumbersView is a subview sheet)

Comment: can anyone help? Is anyone there?